# How to pass multiple DB files to locate?

Tags: shell, zsh, home, locate

I want to pass multiple DB files to the `locate` command, like this:

```
locate -d ~/.a_locate.db:~/.b_locate.db: -Ai file_to_find
```

But this gives me this error:

```
locate: can not stat () `~/.b_locate.db': No such file or directory
```

The man page for locate says:

> -d, --database DBPATH
>           Replace the default database with DBPATH.
>
> DBPATH is a :-separated  list of database file names. If more than one --database
>   option is specified, the resulting path is a concatenation of the
>   separate paths.

I don't clearly understand what is meant by 'concatenation of separate', What am I doing wrong? I tried giving the full path (`/home/user/.b_locate.db`) and it worked. Can someone explain this behaviour?

(I'm using `mlocate` package in Arch linux)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second `~` isn’t being expanded; try

```
locate -d "${HOME}/.a_locate.db:${HOME}/.b_locate.db:" -Ai file_to_find
```

instead, or, since this is zsh, just

```
locate -d $HOME/.a_locate.db:$HOME/.b_locate.db: -Ai file_to_find
```

The reason is that `~/` is only expanded at the beginning of a shell word. A shell word only ends at whitespace (as far as it matters here — the actual rules are much more complicated). `~/foo:~/bar` is a single word, which begins with `~/` so the leading `~` is expanded to your home directory, but the middle `~` is nothing special so it stays a tilde. There's an exception on the right-hand side of an assignment: in `PATH=~/foo:~/bar`, `~/` is expanded after the `=` assignment sign and after a `:` on the right-hand side.

Comment: Are you psychic :p Yes, this works, and so does `locate -d "~/.a_locate.db:${HOME}/.b_locate.db:" -Ai file_to_find`. Would you happen to know the reason behind this behavior?

Comment: @A.K.S.H. See the edited answer.

Comment: Multiple -d options are allowed. So I think it's ok with : locate -d ~/.a_locate.db -d ~/.b_locate.db: -Ai file_to_find . Note that the -A option dont' exist on OpenBSD.